# CSS for a link which is in a div

Tags: css

In the theme which i'm using has this code

```
<div id="header">
<div class="container section header clearfix">
<a id="logo" class="logo" rel="home" title="Home" href="/xx/">
<img alt="Home" src="http://192.168.1.1/xx/sites/default/files/logo_0.png">
</a>
<div id="user-links" class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="name-and-slogan">
</div>
<div class="region region-header">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I just need move the logo  on to the left side bit. using css
please advice;

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? I'm not going to do it for you.

Comment: yes   #header a{
top : -50;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try:

```
#logo {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
. clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

You'll need to replace the width, height and margin values with whatever your logo size is. You can adjust the margin to whatever you like.